# Simple Plane pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

So, I am having a lot of troubles visualizing the following system.

The point of suspension of a plane simple pendulum of mass m and length l is constrained to move along a horizontal track and is connected to a point on the circumference of a uniform flywheel of mass M and radius a through a massless connecting rod also of length a, as shown in the figure. The flywheel rotates about a center fixed on the track. Find the hamiltonian for the combined system and determine Hamilton's equation of motion.

Here is my idea so first of all I would construct the Lagrangian and then from it I will get the hamiltonian, so for this I need to determine the kinetic energy and the potential energy.

I am having troubles constructing the cartesian coordinates of this thing which the only thing that I need I know how to do everything else.

Is the following correct

$x = l\sin(\theta) - a(\omega)t$? where I measure the angle of the regular m pendulum with respect to vertical and the other one with respect to horizontal ? and $\omega$ is how fast the flywheel rotates.

[image]

Comment: The flywheel doesn't actually rotate, right? It oscillates around its centre point?

Comment: @Gert I think the flywheel is capable of rotating - but I imagine we are interested only in small angle deviations from equilibrium.

Comment: @Floris: *capable* of rotating but really just oscillating, is how I see it.

Comment: Are the arms $a$ and $l$ perpendicular to each other? Easier to visualise that way.

Comment: the flywheel rotates but a doesn't is rigid so it just moves in x and y direction it doesn't like deform or anything like that.

Comment: @Gert Here is what I am thinking $x = acos(\omega*t) - lsin(\theta)$

Comment: I don't think the angle of the pendulum comes into the expression for the displacement of the point of suspension. Instead it is just $2a\cos\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle of displacement of the flywheel. The flywheel adds inertia to the system and thus affects the apparent length of the pendulum (infinitely heavy and the point of suspension is fixed; infinitely lift and the pendulum slides around)

Comment: So the point of intersection between $a$ and $l$ is fixed on the track?

Comment: well, here is how I imagine this system as a goes up and down due to rotation of M, then m will also have simple pendulum movement i.e move left and right like a simple pendulum.

Comment: The Hamiltonian should not be complicated to find, for small angle oscillation.

Comment: what do you think of my expression above do you agree with it ?

Comment: Might tell you later ;). Calculate total energy (is constant if no friction). Derive to time ($\frac{d}{dt}$) to get equation of motion.

Comment: alright I will derive the hamiltonian and check if the derivative with respect to time is zero since here energy is conserved, and that will give an indication of whether it is correct or not.

Comment: I've got a solution based on one approximation. By deriving the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This picture might help:

[image]

This assumes the flywheel is fixed on the track, the point of suspension can move along the track, but there is a rod from the point of suspension to the rim of the flywheel. This means there are two equal angles $\alpha$ and $x$, the displacement of the point of suspension from the furthest possible location, is given by

$$x = 2a(1-\cos\alpha)$$

Alternatively, if you use the center of the flywheel as your origin (might be more sensible) you find that

$$x = 2a\cos\alpha$$

Since this is a homework-like question, I will for now leave the rest up to you. Can you take it from here?

Comment: yeah I understand now how to do it

Comment: I am sorry I have a question what about the y-coordinates I got my x coordinate to be as follows
$x = 2acos(\alpha) - lsin(\theta)$, where I didn't assume it is fixed, where $\theta$ above is the angle the vertical makes with the pendulum above.

Comment: does the $\alpha$ y-component matter for the potential energy of small m ?

Comment: never mind I get it now after I did demonstration of the above with two pens it doesn't matter and the angle of $\theta$ will fix the orientation of the potential energy of mass m.

Comment: Exactly - because the pivot point is fixed on the track them potential energy only depends on $\theta$

Answer (score 0):

As both the flywheel and pendulum oscillate at the same frequency (same $\omega$), calculate the kinetic energy of both in function of $\omega$ and their inertial moments. Add them up, that gives you $K$.

Calculate potential energy of the pendulum in function of $\theta$. The flywheel's potential energy is independent of $\theta$, so leave it out. That gives you $U$.

Add $K$ and $U$ to get total energy, which in the absence of friction is constant (time invariant).

Derive that equation for $t$, apply the small angle approximation, rework a bit and obtain a very simple equation of motion, from which $\omega$ can be derived easily.